# hook a script to apt-get

Tags: mount, apt, tmp

I have `/tmp` on a separate partition, and mounted with `noexec`. I am using Debian.

The installation of some packages fails, because the post-installation scripts of some packages need to run from `/tmp`.

I was wondering if it would be possible to "hook" a simple script to `apt-get`, which would be run every time before `apt-get`, and remount `/tmp` to `exec`. And similarly, remount it to `noexec` after `apt-get` has finished.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `dpkg`'s hook system to remount it -- put this in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00exectmp`:

```
DPkg::Pre-Invoke {"mount -o remount,exec /tmp";};
DPkg::Post-Invoke {"mount -o remount /tmp";};
```

Comment: perfect, clean solution!

Answer (score -2):

Mumble, you can simply replace `apt-get` with a script of yours.

Move `apt-get` to `real-apt-get` and, then, create a script called `apt-get` like this one:

```
#!/bin/sh

mount -o remount -o ... /tmp
real-apt-get "$@"
mount -o remount -o ... -o noexec /tmp
```

In any case, I do not like this solution. It is easier change the temporary directory environment variable when you need it. Something like (sh style):

```
mkdir /root/mytmp
TMPDIR=/root/mytmp
export TMPDIR
apt-get ...
rm -rf /root/mytmp
```

This way apt-get will use `/root/mytmp` as temporary dir. No need to change the system.

Comment: ... until the `apt` package is upgraded, that is.  I don't recommend messing with files supplied by packages.

Comment: As per previous comment, overwriting package supplied binaries is a really bad idea...! The accepted answer is superior, but even if you did want to go ahead with something like this, instead, save the script as /usr/local/bin/apt-get (or better still, probably ~/bin/apt-get assuming no other users will want it; also make sure it's in your path). Then instead of calling "real-apt-get" just use the full path /usr/bin/apt-get. Then you can get updates no problems, without breaking your script. (This relies on /usr/local/bin being before /usr/bin in PATH - default in Debian).