# How to run a command before download with apt-get?

Tags: apt, hook

How can I run a command before apt-get starts to download a package?

I know about the dpkg pre-invoke hook ( [hook a script to apt-get](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76294/hook-a-script-to-apt-get) ), but that seems to be run after the download.

```
$ apt-get update
Get: 11 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main qemu amd64 1.1.2+dfsg-6a+deb7u7 [115 kB]
Fetched 70.9 MB in 10s (6,776 kB/s)
refreshing freenet index
--2015-05-19 15:55:25--  http://127.0.0.1:8888/freenet:USK@oRy7ltZLJM-w-kcOBdiZS1pAA8P-BxZ3BPiiqkmfk0E,6a1KFG6S-Bwp6E-MplW52iH~Y3La6GigQVQDeMjI6rg,AQACAAE/deb.mempo.org/-42/
```

What we need is to run a command *before* the download. More exactly: The script must run after calling apt-get but before apt-get accesses any online resource.

Is there something like a Pre-Download hook?

It is important that the installation can be done without having to replace the script apt-get (and without doing anything else which could be undone by an update).

Comment: You could declare a function named `apt-get` which would itself call the real `apt-get`. Depending on the scope you want it to have, the function could be declared either in `/etc/profile` or `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: What exactly does "The script must run after calling apt-get but before apt-get accesses any online resource" mean? What part of the producion apt-get needs to be running before your hook can execute properly?

Comment: @jthill we need to trigger a download of a given URL before any other URL gets accessed. The reason is that we download from freenet (decentralized anonymous datastore used as deb repository) and we want to trigger one aggressive search for the most recent version before downloading anything.

Comment: From comments, you're asking how to replace a system command in a way that can't be bypassed and can't be removed even by the system's installer. You're asking how to rootkit the system.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could describe your use case. Or in other words, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @jithill: I’m not asking how to rootkit the system, but how to trigger a blocking search for the most recent version of the p2p repository before accessing it. For that I have to issue a download from a specific URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First determine where is apt-get using `whereis apt-get` or `which apt-get`; I will assume it's in */usr/bin/apt-get*

Then create a file in **/usr/local/bin/apt-get** with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
# (commands to run before apt-get)
exec /usr/bin/apt-get "$@"
```

now `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/apt-get`.

This should survive all upgrades of the distribution but it should not change the behavior of apt-get (aside from running the command before doing anything else). As bonus, it could parse the command line arguments to only run the command when it is truly needed.

*(This answer builds upon the [answer from
Mohammad Etemaddar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204433/34896), merged with the feedback from muru)*

Answer (score 10):

What about using apt pre/post-invoke hooks?

Essentially it is similar to dpkg pre/post-invoke hooks but for apt (which I'm assuming is actually the important one in your usage scenario). AFAIK there are others but I've only used like this.

E.g.

```
$ sudo cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/05new-hook
APT::Update::Pre-Invoke {"your-command-here"};
```

Comment: Apt doesn't provide a pre-invoke hook for Upgrade or Install though, so this only works for `apt-get update`.

Comment: True, but I was answering the question specifically! :) You can use dpkg hooks (as per the OP) for anything which requires pre/post install tweaks.

Comment: Kind of; assuming that update is always run before upgrade/install. Hooking all commands before network access occurs appears to be impossible with the currently (2017-05-17) available apt hooks. This is still the best answer for scripting but it doesn't help for things like existing automatic update scripts.

Comment: Oh ok, I get you now. Sorry; yes you have a really good point. So you can tweak apt-get update, but apt-get install will still download, before the dpkg hooks will run?! Hmmm, that really sucks!

Comment: What you are trying to do? If you want auto updates but only install from specific repos (e.g. Debian security), then you can use cronapt with a script like TurnKey's cronapt script[1]. Split your sources.list entries into separate files; the ones that you want auto updates from go in security.sources.list. [1] https://github.com/turnkeylinux/common/blob/master/conf/turnkey.d/cronapt

Comment: I'm trying to perform network detection to disable apt when my laptop's VMs are roaming off my home network. The best solution I've come up with in the past couple days is a custom proxy script that returns HTTP 500 when it isn't on the right network.

Comment: Yeah sounds a bit tricky. Depending on what VM software you're using, and your host OS, but if you're using VirtualBox and your host OS is Linux, you could perhaps use a network hook (ifup/ifdown hooks) to adjust VBox's networking (via VBoxManage) to host-only when you're roaming? I don't know enough about Win/Mac networking, but I'd assume something similar could be done there too? I'm not even sure it would work and it may not meet your needs anyway (if you still want remote network access (just not apt).

Answer (score 2):

You can use an "alias" in the .bashrc file. For example, put that in your root .bashrc file:

```
alias apt-get='echo blahblah && apt-get'
```

Command-line arguments will be added automatically to the end of the alias.

Just replace `echo blahblah` by the command you need.

But in this case, it only works when you're executing commands as **root** (not sudo).

Comment: Is it possible to put this alias in normal user profile in order to use it by sudo?

Comment: Yes, I thik so. Try: `alias apt-get='echo blahblah && sudo apt-get'`. Then you only need to type in the terminal for example -  `apt-get update` without `sudo`, and you'll be asked for a sudo password automatically.

Comment: it's true. of course then 'echo blahblah' won't work under su privileges.

Comment: It might be better to use a shell function or a script (in `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin`), because aliases don't handle arguments well.

Answer (score 1):

First determine where is apt-get using `whereis apt-get`; I will assume it's in */usr/bin/apt-get*

as *muru* says, You can create a script named `apt-get` in `/usr/local/bin/` which is before `/usr/bin` in Debian and Ubuntu `$PATH`. Then put the following code to it (`/usr/local/bin/apt-get`):

```
#!/bin/bash
commands to run before apt-get
/usr/bin/apt-get "$@"
```

*Thanks **muru** for offer as comment.*

**Other way:**

Of course there's another way which is not better than previous one.

You can `mv /usr/bin/apt-get /usr/bin/apt-get2`

Then create a file in **/usr/bin/apt-get** with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
commands to run before apt-get
apt-get2 "$@"
```

now `chmod +x /usr/bin/apt-get`

Comment: does this survive a dist-upgrade?

Comment: Yes. `$@` causes script to work with every arguments.

Comment: Eek. If you want to create a replacement, put it in `/usr/local/bin`, which comes before `/usr/bin` in the default PATH in Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: This is really bad advice, sorry. (a) The `apt-get` executable is located in `/usr/bin/apt-get`, not `sbin`. (b) Don't mess with system commands. As muru says, you can create a local override in `/usr/local/bin`, though even that is not a good solution.

Comment: @muru /usr/local/bin sounds like a possible way to go - I hadn’t thought of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try an alias in the `.bashrc` file. It only works when logged in to the account that the file corresponds to.
The syntax of an alias is:

`alias newcommand='command1; command2; command3'`
So your line might look a bit like this:

`alias apt-get='firstcommand; apt-get'`

Or this:

`alias apt-get='firstcommand && apt-get'`

With the second, `apt-get` will only execute if `firstcommand` succeeds.

Comment: Aside from clarifying the root / normal user issue, this is essentially a reiteration of the first answer.